# Android text-to-speech has seemingly random delay / queuing while screen is off

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech

I have an issue with text-to-speech where some of the utterances are randomly delayed. I have a code that invokes TTS once every minute, and sometimes, nothing happens. This only happens when the phone's screen is off.

I logged the events to a text file and saw that whenever the speech does not happen when it should, the utterance progress starts but does not stop. If the screen is turned on OR in most cases (but not always) another TTS event is received, the speeches are uttered in the correct order, albeit late.

At first I thought this was a power-saving issue related to the foreground service, but based on the logs, `textToSpeech.speak()` is called at correct times, every single time. I haven't found anything else from the code than the fact that progress listener's `onSpeakStop()` does not get invoked. It's like the TTS is some sort of limbo.

What could be causing this? The TTS is initialized like this:

```
textToSpeech = TextToSpeech(context, initListener)
textToSpeech.setAudioAttributes(
    AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SPEECH)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_COMMUNICATION_INSTANT)
        .setFlags(AudioAttributes.FLAG_AUDIBILITY_ENFORCED)
        .build()
)
```

And the speech is invoked like this:

```
val result =
        textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, utteranceId)
```

Everything else works fine (foreground service running as intended, TTS working while screen is on etc.), it's only the case when the screen is off that sometimes, messages get delayed until

- Screen is turned on (all queued speeches are uttered in order)
- Another speech is added (only works intermittently; speeches are uttered in FIFO order)

Comment: The cause is unclear without more debugging … and it may not even really be a “bug” as it  seems most likely to be the OS (Android) power / audio management having an effect on the tts engine/service.  Since using queue_add is not going to play until the previous utterances onDone is called (and youre saying that is hangjng),  Its possible that using queue_flush instead may help.

Comment: Also as a work-around you could try re-initializing a new tts instance for every utterance.